# How to make an image random but not repeat by modifying this code

Tags: javascript, random, repeat

The below code is the only code that worked on my site (built w an online template) alll other javascript crashed.  (I am very novice at web programming) Is there a simple change I can make to this code in order to not have a repeat picture till all the pictures were displayed?

```
var delay=7000 //set delay in miliseconds
var curindex=0

var randomimages=new Array()
randomimages[0]="content/indsidebar1(2).jpg"
randomimages[1]="content/indsidebar2.jpg"
randomimages[2]="content/indsidebar3(3).jpg"
randomimages[3]="content/indsidebar6a.jpg"
randomimages[4]="content/indsidebar5.jpg"
randomimages[5]="content/indsidebar6.jpg"
randomimages[6]="content/indsidebar7.jpg"
randomimages[7]="content/indsidebar8.jpg"
randomimages[8]="content/indsidebar9.jpg"
randomimages[9]="content/indsidebar10.JPG"
randomimages[10]="content/commersidebar1.JPG"
randomimages[11]="content/commersidebar2.JPG"
randomimages[12]="content/commersidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[13]="content/commersidebar5.JPG"
randomimages[14]="content/commersidebar6.JPG"
randomimages[15]="content/commersidebar7.JPG"
randomimages[16]="content/ressidebar1.JPG"
randomimages[17]="content/ressidebar2.JPG"
randomimages[18]="content/ressidebar3.JPG"
randomimages[19]="content/ressidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[20]="content/communsidebar1.JPG"
randomimages[21]="content/communsidebar3.JPG"
randomimages[22]="content/communsidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[23]="content/communsidebar5.JPG"
randomimages[24]="content/communsidebar6.JPG"
randomimages[25]="content/communsidebar7.JPG"
randomimages[26]="content/communsidebar8.JPG"
randomimages[27]="content/communsidebar10.JPG"
randomimages[28]="content/undersidebar1.jpg"
randomimages[29]="content/undersidebar2(1).jpg"
randomimages[30]="content/undersidebar3.jpg"
randomimages[31]="content/undersidebar4.jpg"
randomimages[32]="content/servicesidebar1.jpg"
randomimages[33]="content/servicesidebar2.jpg"
randomimages[34]="content/servicesidebar6.jpg"
randomimages[35]="content/servicesidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[36]="content/servicesidebar5.JPG"

var preload=new Array()

for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
{
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
}

document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+
  randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')

function rotateimage()
{
    if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))))
        curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
    else
        curindex=tempindex

    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]
}

setInterval("rotateimage()",delay)
```

Comment: This won't answer your question, but it will help you write better code.  Remove `language="javascript"`, as that's deprecated.  Replace `new Array()` with `[]`, which is the better way of instantiating an array.  And don't use `document.write`; instead, insert the image in the DOM.

Comment: You'll probably want to look into the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for randomizing the order of the images.

Comment: @DerekHenderson Do you have a reference for `[]` being a better way of instantiating an array?

Comment: Yup, let me just Google it for you. 1 sec.

Comment: @DannyBeckett, here you go:  http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/04/the-use-of-literals-vs-constructors/

Comment: @DerekHenderson Thanks for that! Just made a change to a project to add an array and used `var myVar = new Array();` - I've just changed it to `var myVar = [];`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with suggestion by `Derek Henderson` for better coding.

Probably you can use the following logic:

1. Copy randomimages to original_randomimages array.
2. Pick & display a random picture from array randomimages(for example ith element).
3. Remove the displayed picture from randomimages array using splice method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
4. Repeat step 2 & 3 until randomimages array is empty.
5. Copy original_randomimages to randomimages.
6. Repeat again from step 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the randomization after a random generation of images, you can write a function similar to this and then call the function again once it exits the while loop.

```
var delay=7000 //set delay in miliseconds
var curindex=0

var randomimages=new Array()
randomimages[0]="content/indsidebar1(2).jpg"
randomimages[1]="content/indsidebar2.jpg"
randomimages[2]="content/indsidebar3(3).jpg"
randomimages[3]="content/indsidebar6a.jpg"
randomimages[4]="content/indsidebar5.jpg"
randomimages[5]="content/indsidebar6.jpg"
randomimages[6]="content/indsidebar7.jpg"
randomimages[7]="content/indsidebar8.jpg"
randomimages[8]="content/indsidebar9.jpg"
randomimages[9]="content/indsidebar10.JPG"
randomimages[10]="content/commersidebar1.JPG"
randomimages[11]="content/commersidebar2.JPG"
randomimages[12]="content/commersidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[13]="content/commersidebar5.JPG"
randomimages[14]="content/commersidebar6.JPG"
randomimages[15]="content/commersidebar7.JPG"
randomimages[16]="content/ressidebar1.JPG"
randomimages[17]="content/ressidebar2.JPG"
randomimages[18]="content/ressidebar3.JPG"
randomimages[19]="content/ressidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[20]="content/communsidebar1.JPG"
randomimages[21]="content/communsidebar3.JPG"
randomimages[22]="content/communsidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[23]="content/communsidebar5.JPG"
randomimages[24]="content/communsidebar6.JPG"
randomimages[25]="content/communsidebar7.JPG"
randomimages[26]="content/communsidebar8.JPG"
randomimages[27]="content/communsidebar10.JPG"
randomimages[28]="content/undersidebar1.jpg"
randomimages[29]="content/undersidebar2(1).jpg"
randomimages[30]="content/undersidebar3.jpg"
randomimages[31]="content/undersidebar4.jpg"
randomimages[32]="content/servicesidebar1.jpg"
randomimages[33]="content/servicesidebar2.jpg"
randomimages[34]="content/servicesidebar6.jpg"
randomimages[35]="content/servicesidebar4.JPG"
randomimages[36]="content/servicesidebar5.JPG"

var preload=new Array()

for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
{
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
}


var checkArray = [];
var length = randomimages.length;

function generateImages () {

    var i = generateRandomValue();
    if (checkArray.length <= length){
        if(checkArray.indexOf(i) === -1) {
          document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[i]+'">')
          checkArray.push(i);
       } else {
          generateImages();      
       }
    } else if (checkArray.length === length) {
        checkArray = [];
        generateImages();
    }

 }

function  generateRandomValue () {

 return Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length));

}

function rotateimage()
{
    if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))))
        curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
    else
        curindex=tempindex

    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]
}

generateImages();
setInterval("rotateimage()", delay);
```

Comment: cool thanks, but i really am novice.  I have no idea where to put this code in regards to what I have.  Can you add this to my code so I can copy it all? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit, but didn't tested it, so please check it, but it should work.

```
<script language="javascript">

var delay=7000; //set delay in miliseconds
var curindex=0;

var randomimages= [];

    randomimages[0]="content/indsidebar1(2).jpg";
    randomimages[1]="content/indsidebar2.jpg";
    randomimages[2]="content/indsidebar3(3).jpg";
    randomimages[3]="content/indsidebar6a.jpg";
    randomimages[4]="content/indsidebar5.jpg";
    randomimages[5]="content/indsidebar6.jpg";
    randomimages[6]="content/indsidebar7.jpg";
    randomimages[7]="content/indsidebar8.jpg";
    randomimages[8]="content/indsidebar9.jpg";
    randomimages[9]="content/indsidebar10.JPG";


    randomimages[10]="content/commersidebar1.JPG";
    randomimages[11]="content/commersidebar2.JPG";
    randomimages[12]="content/commersidebar4.JPG";
    randomimages[13]="content/commersidebar5.JPG";
    randomimages[14]="content/commersidebar6.JPG";
    randomimages[15]="content/commersidebar7.JPG";


    randomimages[16]="content/ressidebar1.JPG";
    randomimages[17]="content/ressidebar2.JPG";
    randomimages[18]="content/ressidebar3.JPG";
    randomimages[19]="content/ressidebar4.JPG";


    randomimages[20]="content/communsidebar1.JPG";
    randomimages[21]="content/communsidebar3.JPG";
    randomimages[22]="content/communsidebar4.JPG";
    randomimages[23]="content/communsidebar5.JPG";
    randomimages[24]="content/communsidebar6.JPG";
    randomimages[25]="content/communsidebar7.JPG";
    randomimages[26]="content/communsidebar8.JPG";
    randomimages[27]="content/communsidebar10.JPG";




    randomimages[28]="content/undersidebar1.jpg";
    randomimages[29]="content/undersidebar2(1).jpg";
    randomimages[30]="content/undersidebar3.jpg";
    randomimages[31]="content/undersidebar4.jpg";



    randomimages[32]="content/servicesidebar1.jpg";
    randomimages[33]="content/servicesidebar2.jpg";
    randomimages[34]="content/servicesidebar6.jpg";
    randomimages[35]="content/servicesidebar4.JPG";
    randomimages[36]="content/servicesidebar5.JPG";


//You are not using preload anywhere so it is not necessary

var irand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length));

document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[irand]+'">');

var shown = [];
shown[irand] = true;

function rotateimage()
{
    var itemp = Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length));
    if(shown[itemp])
       return;
    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[itemp];
    shown[itemp] = true;
    if (shown.length == 36)
        shown = [];
}

setInterval(rotateimage, delay);

    </script>
```

**Update:**
Corrected version:

```
<script language="javascript">

    var delay=7000; //set delay in miliseconds
    var curindex=0;

    var randomimages= [];

        randomimages[0]="content/indsidebar1(2).jpg";
        randomimages[1]="content/indsidebar2.jpg";
        randomimages[2]="content/indsidebar3(3).jpg";
        randomimages[3]="content/indsidebar6a.jpg";
        randomimages[4]="content/indsidebar5.jpg";
        randomimages[5]="content/indsidebar6.jpg";
        randomimages[6]="content/indsidebar7.jpg";
        randomimages[7]="content/indsidebar8.jpg";
        randomimages[8]="content/indsidebar9.jpg";
        randomimages[9]="content/indsidebar10.JPG";


        randomimages[10]="content/commersidebar1.JPG";
        randomimages[11]="content/commersidebar2.JPG";
        randomimages[12]="content/commersidebar4.JPG";
        randomimages[13]="content/commersidebar5.JPG";
        randomimages[14]="content/commersidebar6.JPG";
        randomimages[15]="content/commersidebar7.JPG";


        randomimages[16]="content/ressidebar1.JPG";
        randomimages[17]="content/ressidebar2.JPG";
        randomimages[18]="content/ressidebar3.JPG";
        randomimages[19]="content/ressidebar4.JPG";


        randomimages[20]="content/communsidebar1.JPG";
        randomimages[21]="content/communsidebar3.JPG";
        randomimages[22]="content/communsidebar4.JPG";
        randomimages[23]="content/communsidebar5.JPG";
        randomimages[24]="content/communsidebar6.JPG";
        randomimages[25]="content/communsidebar7.JPG";
        randomimages[26]="content/communsidebar8.JPG";
        randomimages[27]="content/communsidebar10.JPG";




        randomimages[28]="content/undersidebar1.jpg";
        randomimages[29]="content/undersidebar2(1).jpg";
        randomimages[30]="content/undersidebar3.jpg";
        randomimages[31]="content/undersidebar4.jpg";



        randomimages[32]="content/servicesidebar1.jpg";
        randomimages[33]="content/servicesidebar2.jpg";
        randomimages[34]="content/servicesidebar6.jpg";
        randomimages[35]="content/servicesidebar4.JPG";
        randomimages[36]="content/servicesidebar5.JPG";


    //You are not using preload anywhere so it is not necessary

    var irand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length));

    document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[irand]+'">');

    var shown = [];
    shown[irand] = true;

    function rotateimage()
    {
        var itemp = Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length));
        if(shown[itemp])
           return;
        document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[itemp];
        shown[itemp] = true;
        if (shown.length == 36)
            shown.pop();
    }

    setInterval(rotateimage, delay);

        </script>
```

Comment: tried it.  Works for 1 rotation of pictures but then stops once all pictures cycled through....

Comment: As for the `preload[]`, that was allowing the browser to load and cache the images before they'd be needed. They wouldn't all have been loaded before use (as there was no waiting for them to finish loading) but a good number of them would have been. So while not _strictly_ necessary, it could help with the user experience.

Comment: Yeah XGundam05, but without caching it is is better for the server so if the user does not wait for viewing all 37 pictures there is a smaller occupancy rate for the server.

Comment: @ThomasKos, this is true. I guess it really just depends on the point of the application.

Comment: @user2394920 Allright, please change the line where `shown = [];` to `shown.pop();`. It should now work perfectly.

Comment: tried changing preload to array1 but didnt work.  also there are 2 "preload" commands - which one to change?  Tried one, then the other, then both, but not working

Comment: @user2394920 Oh yeah, sorry my mistake: change `if (shown.length == 36) shown = [];` to `if (shown.length == 36) shown.pop;`

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, I'd recommend going with a Shuffle of the array (Fisher-Yates is my preferred algorithm for such things). Something akin to:

```
function ShuffleImages(){
    for(var i = randomimages.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        var _tmp = randomimages[i];
        randomimages[i] = randomimages[j];
        randomimages[j] = _tmp;
    }
}
```

This results in no collisions when creating the randomization and ensures no repeated images. You can then just iterate through the array as normal, and shuffle again when you reach the end if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the already shown images from your source

```
<script language="javascript">
var delay = 7000; //set delay in miliseconds
var curindex = 0;

var randomimages = [
    "content/indsidebar1(2).jpg",
    "content/indsidebar2.jpg",
    "content/indsidebar3(3).jpg",
    // add the rest of your images here without , at the end
];

// make a copy of your array as source
var src = randomimages.slice(0);

var preload = [];

for (var n = 0; n < randomimages.length; n++)
{
    preload[n] = new Image();
    preload[n].src = randomimages[n];
}

document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomimages.length)]+'">');

function rotateimage()
{
    if (curindex == (tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length)))){
        curindex = curindex == 0 ? 1 : curindex - 1;
    } else {
        curindex = tempindex;
    }

    document.images.defaultimage.src = randomimages[curindex];

    // remove from source
    ramdomimages.splice(curindex, 1);

    // re-copy src when empty to start new run
    if (randomimages.length == 0) {
        randomimages = src.slice(0);
    }
}

setInterval(
    function() {
        rotateimage();
    }
    , delay
);
</script>
```